# How to Fix render-blocking CSS in html

Tags: html, css, seo

I am using google speed insight for improve my site.I have problem in fixing "Eliminate Render blocking CSS".I have moved my CSS to Footer.But,still i having this error.Anyone can help to get rid of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please move your CSS to the `<head></head>` or otherwise to the top portion of the document, not the footer. CSS is processed first and without being able to process CSS, certain items like backgrounds will not load.

Without having the CSS at the top, your browser will first render raw HTML markup (unstyled) and only after hitting the bottom of the document will it finally learn that styles or an external stylesheet exists.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery for more information, too.